# Rwd minicart instead of sidebar cart

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

Magento 1.9.1.1 with rwd theme. I'm trying to place the existing header minicart block (not the sidebar.phtml) within a cms page . I've tried using following

`{{block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml"}}` 
and I get the icon and count but not the block content.

Comment: in minicart.phtml only cart count is added but the items are rendered in child block you can see there is calling of childhtml block in minicart.phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to call child block through CMS content.

But we can achieve this by CMS page layout section
To get the minicart.phtml file.

Add below code to `CMS  page > design > layout`.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head_cms" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">
                <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart_content_cms" template="checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                    <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/minicart/default.phtml</template></action>
                   <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.cart_promotion_cms" as="cart_promotion" translate="label" module="checkout">
                        <label>Mini-cart promotion block</label>
                    </block>
                    <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions_cms" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                        <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Comment: This is great thanks. The only thing missing when it renders is <table class="info-wrapper"> which contains the price and editable quantity box. How would I also get that?

Comment: Seems to be calling sidebar/default.phtml rather than minicart/default.phtml

Comment: Clearing the cache solved that issue of calling sidebar/default.phtml. So using the above answer and also editing minicart/items.phtml using this solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/26146/9959 puts the whole minicart layout into sidebar.